# VB.NET - Regular Expression to search a partcular format of Tag

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

e.g i have tags like 
`"<ABC_START>"` and  `"<ABC_END>"` in a text file . I need to read only the tags and its between contents rest of the lines i should ignore.how to check the read line which has tag using regular expression.
could anyone please help me to form the reg expression

my text file will look like this
this is comment to be ignored 
my text file will look like this
this is comment to be ignored

```
<abc_start>
ipconfig/all
<abc_end>
```

this is also comment part not to be considered.

i have to read each line of the text file and do further processing of the commands exists in between tags. Now i need to validate the `abc_start` is a tag using regular expression and get the strings till it reaches the end tag.

Comment: tags look like this <abc_start> any commands <abc_end>

Comment: can you give more information about the tags?

Comment: I mean the structure of starting and ending tags

Comment: what have you started?

Comment: my text file will look like this
this is comment to be ignored 
<abc_start>
ipconfig/all
<abc_end>
this is also comment part not to be considered.

i have to read each line of the text file and

Comment: post it in the question along with code for what you have tried

Comment: yes i have posted in question section

Comment: Your  `<abc_start>` and `<abc_end>` will be as they are or they will be something like?

Comment: i have around 30 tags like that. only thing is it will end with _start> and _end> tags

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your request the following code should work for you:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("<.*?_start>(.*?)<.*?_end>", RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim txtFileContent As String = "textextextextext<abc_start>ipconfig/all<abc_end>textextextextextex<DEF_start>ipconfig/none<DEF_end>textextextextextex"
Dim Collection = regex.Matches(txtFileContent)
For Each m As Match In Collection
    Dim commPart As String= m.Groups(1).Value
    MsgBox(commPart)
Next
```

Comment: what incase if the txtfilecontent is not in single line ? i mean i have a file which has multiple lines ?

Comment: Answer updated, RegexOptions added to work for both multi and single lines.

Comment: i have readalllines from the text file and assigned to the matches but i didnt receive any exact mathes :( .

Comment: It should work, show me your code and your text file content.